# Clean way to convert quarterly periods to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, period

**EDIT:**
If you're coming to this question and your string looks like `1996-Q1`, then just use `pd.to_datetime(df['Quarter'])` to convert it to a proper pandas datetime. This question is about solving all the quarter dates that are not in this standard format.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I'm looking for a nice, readable and understandable way (one that you can remember for the next time) to convert `Q3 1996` to a pandas datetime, for example `1996-07-01` in this case.
Until now I found this, but it's mighty ugly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Quarter':['Q3 1996', 'Q4 1996', 'Q1 1997']})
​
df['date'] = (
    pd.to_datetime(
        df['Quarter'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: ''.join(x[::-1]))
))
​
print(df)
   Quarter       date
0  Q3 1996 1996-07-01
1  Q4 1996 1996-10-01
2  Q1 1997 1997-01-01
```

I was hoping the following would work, because it's readable, but unfortunately it doesn't:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Quarter'], format='%q %Y')
```

The problem is also that quarter and year are apparently in the wrong order for pandas to do simple processing.

Can anyone help me find a cleaner way of converting `Q3 1996` to a pandas datetime?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can (and should) use `pd.PeriodIndex` as a first step, then convert to timestamp using `PeriodIndex.to_timestamp`:

```
qs = df['Quarter'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-\1')
qs

0    1996-Q3
1    1996-Q4
2    1997-Q1
Name: Quarter, dtype: object

df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(qs, freq='Q').to_timestamp()
df

   Quarter       date
0  Q3 1996 1996-07-01
1  Q4 1996 1996-10-01
2  Q1 1997 1997-01-01
```

The initial replace step is necessary as `PeriodIndex` expects your periods in the `%Y-%q` format.

---

Another option is to use `pd.to_datetime` after performing string replacement in the same way as before.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Quarter'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-\1'), errors='coerce')
df

   Quarter       date
0  Q3 1996 1996-07-01
1  Q4 1996 1996-10-01
2  Q1 1997 1997-01-01
```

---

If performance is important, you can split and join, but you can do it cleanly:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime([
    '-'.join(x.split()[::-1]) for x in df['Quarter']])

df

   Quarter       date
0  Q3 1996 1996-07-01
1  Q4 1996 1996-10-01
2  Q1 1997 1997-01-01
```

Comment: Both answers are great. Why does pd.to_datetime() need to have Year and Quarter switched around for it to work?

Comment: @SandervandenOord I think it happens to do with the underlying datetime parser being used (`pytz` if I'm not mistaken). But I am not sure. There is no way I'm aware of to specify a format for the PeriodIndex, but it would be nice if you could.

Comment: How can I get dates corresponding to the end of the quarter? Like, Q1 2018 turns into 2018-03-31?

Comment: @ifly6 Had the same question, just put `to_timestamp(how='end')`

Comment: @cs95 First solution does not seem to be working anymore: df['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(qs, freq='Q') I'm getting 'Incorrect dtype'. Using pandas 0.25.3 and pytz 2019.2 Do you have an idea why this is not working anymore? Or am I making a mistake?

Comment: @SandervandenOord there might be something up with qs, I'd need more information. Otherwise, I'll be on my machine in a few hours so if you can wait, I can check it out for you.

Comment: @cs95 I am not in a hurry, just curious why a well appreciated solution of you is partly not working anymore (if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: It seems to me, I need one additional Q before \1 to work properly: `df['Quarter'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-Q\1')` otherwise \1 will be converted to the given month. At least with pd.to_datetime. pandas 1.3.0

Answer (score 12):

Given a quarter format like `2018-Q1`, one can use the built in `pd.to_datetime` function. As a general answer would have to deal with the plethora of ways one can store a quarter-year observation (e.g. `2018:1`, `2018:Q1`, `20181`, `Q1:2018`, etc.), coercing the data into the format *supra* is outside of my answer's scope.

But given a formatted series:

```
formatted_series = formatted_series_supplier() ...
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(formatted_series)
```

For example:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2018-Q1']))
0   2018-01-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And if you're dealing with regulatory data, which almost always reflects the end of the quarter rather than it's start (i.e. instead of 2019-01-01, you want 2019-03-31), you can use offsets like below:

```
df['date'] = df['date'] + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
```

Using the example from above, removing the intermediate result,

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2018-Q1'])) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)
0   2018-03-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Note that the `0` parameter must be provided to `QuarterEnd` if you want correct indexing within the same quarter for the end date. Otherwise, you'll get something like this:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime('2018-03-31') + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd()
Timestamp('2018-06-30 00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 7):

Use slicing by last 4 values with first `2` and convert to datetimes:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Quarter'].str[-4:] + df['Quarter'].str[:2])
```

String operations in pandas are slow, so if no missing values is possible use `list comprehension`:

```
#python 3.6+ 
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime([f'{x[-4:]}{x[:2]}' for x in df['Quarter']])
#python bellow
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(['{}{}'.format(x[-4:], x[:2]) for x in df['Quarter']])
print (df)
   Quarter       date
0  Q3 1996 1996-07-01
1  Q4 1996 1996-10-01
2  Q1 1997 1997-01-01
```