# Convert a Period object to Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, period

I would like to convert an object from `pandas.core.indexes.accessors.PeriodProperties` to a Datetime variable.

As an example, I want to convert a period variable (not a string) with the format "2019Q1" to a datetime format, "2019-03-31".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like `pi` as in

```
pi = pd.PeriodIndex(["2019Q1", "2019Q2"], freq='Q')
```

then you want

```
pi.to_timestamp() + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)

Out[11]: DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-31', '2019-06-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

It is basically described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898482/10197418).