# Plot regression line for dtype Period (Q_DEC) vs int column: python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, seaborn, regplot

I am unable to plot a regression line for a simple dataframe that consists of a period formatted date column and a integer column.  The sample dataframe may be created using below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"quarter": ['2017Q1', '2017Q2', '2017Q3', '2017Q4', 
                               '2018Q1', '2018Q2', '2018Q3', '2018Q4'],
               
               "total": [392, 664, 864,1024,
                        1202, 1375, 1532, 1717]
})
    
df["quarter"] = pd.to_datetime(df["quarter"]).dt.to_period('Q')
```

To generate a regression plot, I am using below code:

```
ax = sns.regplot(
    data=df,
    x='quarter',
    y='total',
)

plt.show();
```

However, I am getting an error as follows:

```
   TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'
```

Converting the Period column to a string/object format did not fix the issue and I am not able to convert it to an integer format either.

Can somebody help provide a way to generate a regression trend line for "total" vs "quarter"?

Comment: [Many datasets contain multiple **quantitative** variables, and the goal of an analysis is often to relate those variables to each other.](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/regression.html#estimating-regression-fits)

Comment: [Clean way to convert quarterly periods to datetime in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898482/7758804)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney. The actual data I am working with is already date-formatted which I converted to quarters using this approach df["quarter"] = df['date'].dt.to_period('Q'). I simply mocked up an example to recreate date-periods in quarters for this post.

Comment: You can't do a regression on a period. You should convert the quarters to dates, and then convert the dates to ordinals, the plot the regression line, and then convert the ordinal numbers on the x-axis to dates for the visualization. Also, unless the raw data is given as only quarterly values, it is better to plot the regression line against the non-aggregated data.

Comment: [How to plot a regression line on a timeseries line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69170874/7758804)

Comment: thanks @TrentonMcKinney - the example is for date formatted series, not quarterly periods.

Comment: Like I said in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78141598/plot-regression-line-for-dtype-period-q-dec-vs-int-column-python?noredirect=1#comment137762413_78141598), you **can't** plot a regression line on periods, you **must** convert them to dates (e.g. 2017Q1 to 2017-03-31), and then to ordinals.